# How to set up webRTC server on ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, webrtc, ubuntu-16.04

I try use this sample on ubuntu16.04
https://github.com/webrtc/samples

when I try to execution

```
node server.js
```

but appeared:

```
const { promisify } = require('es6-promisify')
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/william/samples-gh-pages/web_server/server.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by webRTC server.

WebRTC is executed in JavaScript, so you can create a single html file on your PC and open it in internet browser to test some webrtc things.

You can check various examples here https://webrtc.github.io/samples/

You can inspect these examples in your browser to see how the JavaScript code looks like and what is being done there.

When people speak of webrtc servers they usually mean signaling and TURN (sometimes media server if you need group calls).